# Flutter How can I create divided circle merged image

Tags: flutter

I would like create circle merged image shaped like this.
For example there are teamA and teamB, teamA's logo or image comes to the left side of circle and teamB to the right.

[image]

I tried like so but both images shape is still rectangle like so.

[image]

How can I make it work?

```
new Center(
    child: new Container(
      width: 120.0,
      height: 120.0,
      child: new Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Image.network(
            'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535593063927-5c40dee9cb83?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=3bfc6e7c6043924de9c4746bef6dc969&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60',
            width: 60.0,
            height: 120.0,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
          Image.network(
            'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535603863228-ded98173a95d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=78dee486ac6c9bffda623b83a36ecb1f&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60',
            width: 60.0,
            height: 120.0,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve that, one of them is like this :

```
    new Center(
            child: new Container(
              height: 300.0,
              width: 300.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                border: new Border.all(color: Colors.blue, width: 4.0),
              ),
              child: new Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        image: DecorationImage(
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            image: NetworkImage(
                              'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535593063927-5c40dee9cb83?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=3bfc6e7c6043924de9c4746bef6dc969&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60',
                            ))),
                  ),
                  ClipRect(
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      widthFactor: 0.5,
                                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            image: DecorationImage(
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              image: NetworkImage(
                                  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535603863228-ded98173a95d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=78dee486ac6c9bffda623b83a36ecb1f&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60'),
                            )),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
```

**Result**

[image]